# Adding an extra column to log parser results

Tags: logparser

How to add an extra column with a specified value to log parser results?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to the select clause:

```
SELECT
  Field1,
  Field2,
  'This is my fake column' AS MyField3
FROM
  ...
```